# Create a new line in openxml with powershell

Tags: powershell, openxml

Using powershell with openxml I replace values and output the result as .docx file.

I use

```
[OpenXmlPowerTools.SearchAndReplacer]::SearchAndReplace($original,"John","Jane"+"<w:br/>",$false)
```

I got

```
Jane '<w:br/>' next character goes here
```

I expect

```
Jane  
next character goes here
```

Does anyone see my mistake?

Comment: Looks like `OpenXmlPowerTools` is doing some sanitization and replacement of your string - have you tried just passing in a `\`r\`n`?

Comment: @DanField Thanks for looking into it. Using `\`r\`n` results in `Jane next character goes here`

Answer (score 1):

Line breaks in OpenXML are child nodes of run nodes, and siblings of text nodes.

You're passing in the correct XML node for a break, but it's being inserted into a text node as opposed to being added to the run node.

E.g.

```xml
<w:p>
    <w:r>
        <w:t>
            Jane '<w:br/>' next text goes here
        <w:t/>
    <w:r/>
<w:p/>
```

Instead of:

```xml
<w:p>
    <w:r>
        <w:t>
            Jane
        <w:t/>
        <w:br/>
        <w:t>
            next text goes here
        <w:t/>
    <w:r/>
<w:p/>
```